# Converting user input to uppercase

Tags: linux, unix, awk, tr

I am attempting to create a program in Unix that accesses a data file, adding, deleting, and searching within the file for names and usernames. With this if statement, I am attempting to allow the user to search for data in the file by the first field.

All of the data in the file uses uppercase letters, so I first must convert any text the user input from lowercase to uppercase letters. For some reason, this code is not working with both converting to uppercase and searching and printing the data.

How can I fix it?

```
if [ "$choice" = "s" ] || [ "$choice" = "S" ]; then
        tput cup 3 12
        echo "Enter the first name of the user you would like to search for: "
        tput cup 4 12; read search | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
        echo "$search"
        awk -F ":" '$1 == "$search" {print $3 " " $1 " " $2 }' 
        capstonedata.txt
fi
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add some sample data and expected output. And explain what "this code is not working" means.

Comment: I guess you put the filename on next line? You must put `\ ` at the end to treat it as a command, or put it on the same line `awk -F ":" '$1 == "$search" {print $3 " " $1 " " $2 }' capstonedata.txt`. Otherwise it treats as separate commands.

Comment: you want `read search ; search=$(echo "$search" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'; ...` . AND `awk -v srch="$search" '{ ...}` . Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

This: `read search | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'` will not assign anything to variable `search`.

It should be something like

```
read input
search=$( echo "$input" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' )
```

and it is better to use parameter expansion for [case modification](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification):

```
read input
search=${input^^}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Bash, you can declare a variable to convert to uppercase:

```
$ declare -u search
$ read search <<< 'lowercase'
$ echo "$search"
LOWERCASE
```

As for your code, `read` doesn't have any output, so piping to `tr` doesn't do anything, and you can't have a newline before the file name in the awk statement.

Edited version of your code, minus all the `tput` stuff:

```
# [[ ]] to enable pattern matching, no need to quote here
if [[ $choice = [Ss] ]]; then

    # Declare uppercase variable
    declare -u search

    # Read with prompt
    read -p "Enter the first name of the user you would like to search for: " search
    echo "$search"

    # Proper way of getting variable into awk
    awk -F ":" -v s="$search" '$1 == s {print $3 " " $1 " " $2 }' capstonedata.txt
fi
```

Alternatively, if you want to use only POSIX shell constructs:

```
case $choice in
    [Ss] )
        printf 'Enter the first name of the user you would like to search for: '
        read input
        search=$(echo "$input" | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]')
        awk -F ":" -v s="$search" '$1 == s {print $3 " " $1 " " $2 }' capstonedata.txt
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk is not shell (google that). Just do:

```
if [ "$choice" = "s" ] || [ "$choice" = "S" ]; then
        read search
        echo "$search"
        awk -F':' -v srch="$search" '$1 == toupper(srch) {print $3, $1, $2}' capstonedata.txt
fi
```